# Working with new Promise inside a array map

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I'm working with a software that has 3 phases:

Phase one, phase two and phase 3.

In the phase one i'm using exiftool to extract metadata from the files, but the process is async, so i need wait the result before call the next phase, for that, i'm using the following code:

```
MAP.files = files.scan((file) => {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    exiftool(file, (error, metadata) =>  {
      file.error    = error
      file.metadata = metadata
      resolve(file)
    });

  });
});
```

The returning is array with a bunch of objects, like this:

```
[ Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }
  .....
]
```

The phase two, isn't async, and i need access the file just like the previous phase, using array.map, like this:

```
MAP.files.text = MAP.files((file) => {

   //To be able to access the real file, i need use then, like this:


   file.then((realFile) => {

     console.log(realFile) // real file with properties
   });


});
```

In the next phase (phase 3), i want do the same:

```
MAP.files.final = MAP.files.text((file) => {

});
```

My question is: The THEN function, can't i scape from it? Do i need use file.then in each phase after phase one??

Comment: Just use `Promise.all`?

Comment: No, you cannot escape from asynchrony.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you reword your question to highlight your exact problem, and describe it more?

Comment: That's not my question Bergi, i want know if i need use the "then(...)" in the nexts phases..

Comment: @TennysonH I update my question, could you see?

Comment: Yes. You can only access your data after using a callback. That callback is either `then` if you're doing them individually, or `Promise.all`, like Bergi said, if you want to do something after _all_ the promises complete.

Comment: You should `promisifyAll()` the libs you are using and should not use `new Promise` which is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Your comment is not helping. I don't have much knowledge with Promises, could you help?

Comment: Why do i need use promisifyAll??

Comment: Only the phase one is async, shouldn't i avoid promisify the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like using `Promise.all` will help you.

E.g. if you have an array of promises...

```
var p = [p1, p2, p3]

Promise.all(p).then( (results) => 
   /* results is an array of the results of each promise in p */
);
```

See http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all for documentation on `Promise.all`

Comment: Hei @TennyshonH, can you check my update? I think now is clear.

Comment: Hei Tennyshon. What about if i need assign the async code inside the promise.all to the MAP.text??